Retrieve all static methods with an attribute (Unity, Reflection)
At the moment I'm using a trivial enumeration of all assemblies in AppDomain.CurrentDomain, which is clearly not efficient. Is there any way to get only my builds or is it somehow convenient to specify them via Editor?
foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.IsInterface || (type.IsAbstract && !type.IsSealed))
        continue;
        
        foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            object[] attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BootstrapMethodAttribute), false);
            
            if (attributes.Length == 0)
            continue;

            BootstrapMethodAttribute attribute = (BootstrapMethodAttribute)attributes[0];
            attribute.Method = method;
            bootstrapMethods.Add(new BootstrapTarget(attribute.Order, null, method));
        }
    }
}


How is it related to the editor? What do you mean “not efficient”? You enumerate all assemblies because you don't know which assembly contains the methods you are looking for. You are not telling us anything about how one assembly is different from other ones. You can mark the assembly somehow to be considered. Do you want to consider such a design? If you can, I can explain it in detail. Additionally, you can mark the assembly the way that you won't need to traverse its method.
